# Force Child Components to Rerender (Make API Call)

Tags: reactjs

Id like to create a view that stays up to date, by making new API calls every minute. Basically needing to trigger all child components to rerender, and make their API call again. Ive tried using forceUpdate(), as well as updating the prop (below). The timer is working, but the child components are not calling the API for more data

Currently the component looks like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {

  state = {
    time: 0
  };

  private interval : any;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this._refreshPage.bind(this), 1000);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  _refreshPage() {
    console.log("refresh");
    //this.forceUpdate();
    this.setState({ time: Date.now() });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="MyComponent">

          <Api endpoint={'/api/revenue/total_revenue?' + this.state.time} loadData={true}>
            <Table />
          </Api>
...
```

Api:

```
class Api extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this._makeApiCall(this.props.endpoint);
  }
...
```

I was hoping here, that as the prop query parameter changed with the nuw timestamp (which it does), the `Api` component would rerender and call the "new" endpoint. The prop does change, however the API does not get called again, why?

Answer (score 1):

Use a different [lifecycle method](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#updating).  componentDidMount is only called the first time the component is added to the dom,  not during any subsequent re-renders. shouldComponentUpdate is probably the one you want.

Comment: Which lifecycle would be appropriate for this?

Comment: Just edited.  shouldComponentUpdate is probably the one you want, but componentWillReceiveProps would work as well.  Just not componentDidMount as that's only called once.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, or provide an example? Moving  `_makeApiCall` into `shouldComponentUpdate` doesnt seem to work correctly

Comment: ```shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps: any) {
    if (nextProps != this.props) {
      this._makeApiCall(this.props.endpoint);
      return true;
    } else { return false}
  }```

Comment: It strangely updates every second even if the props havent changed